# Kivymd Icon Button Appearing as a Line

Tags: python, button, kivy, icons, kivymd

Let me start by saying thank you for any time you give this. I have been working on a project and I noticed that when I tried to use a Icon Button with a personal image on my phone, it would appear only as a line with vague coloring referencing the original image. [Grid View with icon buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMiyF.jpg)

The button itself is the right size, but the icon just appears as that line. I tried the same thing without being in a grid and as a single button on the screen, and it appeared the same way. Without me posting my code for now, what might be causing this issue. I'm using kivymd=1.0.2.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.